# How to modify back the Context on a Python Click program or sharing modified value between commands

Tags: python, python-click

I am aware we can retrieve a value from the ctx obj like in `reference1 = obj["reference1"]` but I want to update the value back, I've noticed that after modifying the value the `reference1` is still `None`

```py
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    ctx.obj = {
        "reference1": None,
    }



@click.pass_obj
def cli(obj, value1, value2):
  reference1 = obj["reference1"]

  # I want to do the following:
  obj["reference1"] = "my updated value"
```

Calling `obj["reference1"]` will return `None` next time

Is there a way to modify the context or passing a value to another command with a sort of global variable?

Answer (score 0):

So, I've amended your code to this:

```py
@click.group(chain=True)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    ctx.obj = {
        "reference1": None,
    }


@cli.command()
@click.pass_obj
def foo(obj):
    # I want to do the following:
    obj["reference1"] = "my updated value"


@cli.command()
@click.pass_obj
def bar(obj):
    print(obj["reference1"])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

And invoked it like:

```
python main.py bar foo bar
```

The result is:

```
None <--- from first invoking `bar`
my updated value <--- from invoking `bar` after `foo`
```

Alternatively, you can change `foo` to

```py
@cli.command()
@click.pass_obj
def foo(obj):
    # I want to do the following:
    obj["reference1"] = "my updated value"
    click.get_current_context().invoke(bar)
```

and just call it as `python main.py foo`.

Comment: Hi, it kind of works, because it's true it works with the chaining, but I was wondering if there's a way of doing this without the chaining?

Comment: @Absulit have you tried the other definition of foo, without any chaining?

Comment: I actually did, but it didn't work on my particular case because I'm using the Custom Multi Commands option and each command is on a separate file
 https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/commands/#custom-multi-commands

Comment: Mind updating your code to provide a reproducible example then?